# Design patterns accepting dates

Tags: design-patterns, date-format

One of my friend had a interview and this is the question that was asked,

A web application should accept dates on any pattern,

ie it could mm-dd-yy/dd-mm-yyyy/dd-mm-yy,Jan-dd-yyyy..any date pattern you can think..

He needs a function which will validate character by character once the user enters.

How do we handle this?

Comment: You cannot accurately distinguish between mm-dd-yy and dd-mm-yy 100% of the time without some user input take 06-07-12. Is it June 7, or July 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but if the question is about **validating** then it isn't about decoding a date, but just making sure that a date is not invalid. That is to say not letting you type 29-02-2011, or 02-29-11 and so on and so forth.

What I would do is write a function to first of all split the date into parts. Given the question we can say that the date will be in numeric form, and as such require a delimiter. Let's use (. - /) as possible delimiters. Cut the date into three parts using the delimiters so you have three different numeric values in memory.

Now for the logic. The first value can be anything (d, m, y). The second value will never really be a year, so it can only be (d, m). The third value will never really be a month, so it can only be (d, y). Keeping that in mind I would do something along the lines of :

1. Try and find the year because it has no range. Any value x where x > 31 has to be the year.
2. Try and find the day. Any value which is not the year and is > 12 has to be the day.
3. Once you have those values do a quick check to make sure that the month <= 12. If it isn't, then the date is invalid.

...but what about ambiguities..?

In the case of ambiguities, like 01-01-01 you will have to figure out using the logic described above what each value *could* be. You need to write a function to test each possibility, given the value of each date segment. I suppose that if  you are trying to validate a date, you would mark a date as valid if it passes at least one test. Basically you would just write a function saying for a given month in a given year (don't forget leap years), what range can the day fall into and then loop through each possible case for a given date.

If the question was to actually decipher the date, then as already explained it is impossible to do so 100% accurately without imposing a format restriction. Your only other option would be to hook a JS event to fire when the field's value is changed, and have text beside the field update to show in long format (January 1st, 2012) what day the software thinks the user has typed in. You could even make that date clickable to allow the user to cycle through different formats if you wished. In the end though, if this is what you were asking then you aren't going to get a concrete way of achieving what you wish to do.